# Using the heap command line tool

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, memory, debug

I am getting a crash while using libgmalloc and I get a complain which says something like

> Failed to VM allocate XYZ bytes
>   Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!

Now I when I encounter this crash I tried to use the heap utility under gdb which was something like

> (gdb) shell heap PROCESS NAME

and also

> (gdb) shell heap -showSizes PROCESS NAME

following the link [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/heap.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/heap)  but all I get in the output is -

> *** Can't get malloced pointers for 562 heap: 
>   print_heap failed  (?/?)  (ffffffff)

where 562 is the PID .What am I missing here?